# How to get CSV headers and Rows Separately Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a `csv` file, after parsing it with `fast-csv`, I get the headers and rows placed in the right order and stored in a folder. Now, I want to get the headers and rows stored separately, for example,

```
csv_headers= ['name', 'age', 'occupation'],
csv_rows = [{name: john doe, age: 23, occupation: engineer}]
```

How can I go about it? I tried looping through the file contents, but that didn't work the way I thought it would. Any help is welcome, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided much information or the loop code. If it's just the csv_rows object you can do a simple loop.

```
var csv_rows = [{name: "john doe", age: 23, occupation: "engineer"}];
var headings = [];
var rows = [];
var csvKeys = Object.keys(csv_rows[0]);
for (var i=0;i<csvKeys.length;i++)
{
    headings[headings.length] = csvKeys[i];
    rows[rows.length] = csv_rows[0][csvKeys[i]];
}
```

[Here is a JS fiddle I made for it](https://jsfiddle.net/dazman/twabkyrv/)

Something like that?